# How to update React component useEffect dependency inside useEffect without creating infinite loop

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component that I need to wait for a store value (members) to update, then remove a member if it meets a condition, and then set that store value again. However this obviously creates a loop.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(members.length > 0) {
        setMembers(members.filter((item) => item.name != 'Bob'));
    }

}, [members]);
```

How is a good way to get around this? The way my app is set up, I really need to do this in this component.

Comment: You should be doing that filtering when you change the members in the first place

Answer (score 0):

You can try an updater state `const [update, setUpdate] = useState(false)` and use `update` as the dependency array. Use `setUpdate(!update)` when the members list updates.

Comment: That's a good idea! However, I still have an issue. The members list always starts as an empty array, so then if update is the useEffect dependency, the useEffect doesn't fire when members is updated with data. And members can be updated after this fact as well.

Comment: I believe you can use 2 dependency arrays like `[members, update]`. At least that's how the quickfix popup shows for me sometimes

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you need to update `members` if it meets a condition, so you can check if it satisfy the condition before set the store value again:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const filterMembers = members.filter((item) => item.name != 'Bob')
  if(members.length > 0 && filterMembers.length > 0) {
    setMembers(filterMembers);
  }
}, [members]);
```

With that, if `members` is not satisfy the condition, `setMembers` doesn't run, and `useEffect` doesn't creates a loop